# Yii2 save Log into Database

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i have some problem with Log with Yii2.
I set Log Targets in this way:

```
'log' => [
    'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
    'flushInterval' => 1,//test
    'targets' => [
        [
          'class' => 'common\components\SaDbTarget',
          'levels' => ['error', 'warning','trace','info'],
          'exportInterval' => 1,//test
          //'categories' => ['application'],
          /*'except' => [
                'yii\db\*',
            ],*/
         ],
       ],
  ],
```

I create my SaDbTarget extending DbTarget Class, and this is working fine because i found in my table some log.
After that, in a controller i tried to set a log like this way

```
public function actionIndex(){
    $searchModel = new CategorySearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    Yii::trace('trace log', __METHOD__);
    Yii::warning('warning log');
    // here is the rest of the code
}
```

I can see this 2 logs into the debug toolbar, but not in my db table.
According to the Docs

> To make each log message appear immediately in the log targets, you
>   should set both flushInterval and exportInterval to be 1

I tried to set this values but still doesn't work.

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

UPDATE
This is my SaDbTarget

```
namespace common\components;

use Yii;
use yii\log\DbTarget;
use yii\log\Logger;

class SaDbTarget extends DbTarget{ 

    //set custom table db for saving log
    public $logTable = 'authlog';

    //overwrite export();
    public function export(){

        $tableName = $this->db->quoteTableName($this->logTable);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $tableName ([[authlog_login]], [[authlog_ip]], [[authlog_area]], [[authlog_act]], [[authlog_time]], [[authlog_data]])
            VALUES (:login, :ip, :area, :act, :time, :data )";

        $command = $this->db->createCommand($sql);

        //Get username
        $user=Yii::$app->user->getId();

        //Get user ip address
        $ip = Yii::$app->request->getUserIP();

        //Get area/controller
        $controller=Yii::$app->controller->uniqueId;

        //Get action
        $event= Yii::$app->controller->module->requestedAction->id;

        //Set timezone
        $time =  Yii::$app->formatter->asDate('now', 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s'); 

        //Set Data
        $data = $this->messages[0];

        $command->bindValues([
            ':login' => $user,
            ':ip' => $ip,
            ':area' => $controller,        
            ':act' => $event,
            ':time' => $time,
            ':data' => $data,
        ])->execute();
    }
```

Comment: can you show the content on `common\components\SaDbTarget` class?

Comment: or maybe you try this:  https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-logging#flushing-exporting

Comment: Tnx for responding, I've added my code.

Comment: I've read about Flushing and Exporting and i set both to 1 but doesn't work.

Comment: I am not sure, if the problem is with your class or something else, can you try using default db log class `DbTarget ` instead of your newly created, if that works we can conclude that problem is not any caching or anything else.

Comment: and make sure `$data = $this->messages[0];` is returning something

Comment: i tried to var_dump($this->messages) and i obtained an array with all the logs.... so now i know what is the problem but i still a little bit confused

Comment: what confusion?

Comment: I can select what log i can send to database using category right? So if  i obtaine an array i need to make a foreach loop to save all of this log ? And how to prevent tthe duplicate?

Comment: you can see the actual class's export function, they are using the foreach loop to loop through the messages.  https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/log/DbTarget.php

Comment: Yes thanks , i'll read the class and then correct my code. I'll suppose my problem is in the SaDbTarget

Comment: Try configuring also table name directly in config e.g. `'logTable' => 'authlog',` . You may also play around with global pattern `*` for categories e.g. `'categories' => ['application*']` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check wether the 'log' component is set on bootstrap?
I think this could be the issue that the dispatcher is not setup and does not pickup the target.

So the bootstrap should look like

```
 [
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
       'log' => [
          ...
       ],    
     ....       
 ]
```

Another way would be to check in the debugger if the dispatcher on the logger is configured correctly.